# Cannot read localhost cookies (return undefined)

Tags: angularjs, cookies, angular-cookies

Trying to use ngCookies to read cookie.
There is a cookie:

```
Name: cookie-name
Content:value
Host:localhost
```

controller.js:

```
var myControllers = angular.module('myControllers', ['ngCookies']);

myControllers.controller('AboutController', [
'$scope', 
'$location',
'$cookies', 
function ($scope, $location, $cookies) {
    $scope.test1 = $cookies.get('cookie-name');
    $scope.test2 = '2';
}]);
```

html is :

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>About Page</h1>
    <p>test1:{{ test1 }}</p>
    <p>test2:{{ test2 }}</p>
</div>
```

But the resulted page is:

```
About Page

test1:

test2:2
```

**UPDATE**

I created the cookie in spring controller.

```
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public AuthenticationResponse logIn(
        @RequestParam(value="username") String username,
        @RequestParam(value="password") String password,
        HttpServletResponse response) 
    {
        /* Test setting cookie */
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("cookie-name", username);
        cookie.setMaxAge(3600*10);
        response.addCookie(cookie);
        AccessToken token = userService.authenticateUser(username, password);
        return new AuthenticationResponse(token.getEncodedToken(), token.getExpiryDate());
    }
```

I have no idea why the cookie cannot be read successfully. Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: By looking at your error message my first check would be to make sure you have included the js-file for ng-Cookies in your index.html or similair.

Comment: you are right. I forgot to add to index.html.

Comment: your cookies have different names: cookiename and cookie-name

Comment: sorry for the confusing posting. I edited the post question, but it seems that some info updated, but others not.